# how to replace the urls in a html page which is being selected in the drop-down containing list of all html pages stored in app data

Tags: c#, html, .net, url, dropdown

I have made a mailer in which I am sending an html page as mail body. There are html pages in my app data and I have used dropdown to select one html page from those pages in app data to be sent as mail body.
The code is:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 getFiles();
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                var list = getFiles();
                dd1.DataSource = list;
                dd1.DataTextField = "Key";
                dd1.DataValueField = "Value";
                dd1.DataBind();
            }
        }
        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                SendHTMLMail();


            void SendHTMLMail()
            {


                MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();

                Msg.From = new MailAddress(txtUsername.Text);

                Msg.To.Add(txtTo.Text);
                Msg.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
                Msg.Body = myString.ToString();
                Msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

                if (fuAttachment.HasFile)
                {
                    string FileName = Path.GetFileName(fuAttachment.PostedFile.FileName);

                    Msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(fuAttachment.PostedFile.InputStream, FileName));
                }

                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(txtUsername.Text, txtpwd.Text);
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Send(Msg);
                Msg = null;
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('Email sent.');", true);
            }

        }
 public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> getFiles()
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/App_Data"));
            var fi = di.EnumerateFiles("*.html", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
            var files = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            foreach (FileInfo file in fi)
            {
                files.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(file.Name, file.FullName));
            }
            return files;
        }
```

Now what I want is, based on the page selected from drop-down, I want to replace  certain links in that html page. There can be any number of links and i don't know about them. What I am concerned about is:

> 1. I want to replace each link with my corresponding links
> 2. I want to know which link was clicked and send the link as a query variable on another page

Also link can be in any form i.e- `http/https/www`